# Image size to fit in fixed size div

Tags: html, css

I have `div` of fixed size `height:45px` and `width:60px` and no other **css** to `div`. This `div` used to show the image uploaded by customer. I want to give the dimensions of image so that the uploaded image will be fit in given div perfectly. I need to give the optimized size so that image will look good in div. First logic I tried to give the image with 45 by 60, 90 by 120 like. 
What is the correct way to solve this.Please guide.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not completely understand your question. Would you like to figure out the correct ratio of the image that the user uploads? Are the images somehow resized by you, or do you only accept images that are a specific size?

Comment: You Want to Vertically and  Horizontally fit the image inide that Div???

Answer (score 6):

```css
div {
  width: 160px;
  height: 145px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFYTl.jpg?s=328&g=1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Best thing is the following:

```
#div-to-contain-image img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will render the image the best as possible. If you need to cover the containing div entirely, you could do the following:

```
#div-to-contain-image img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple solution for you image thumbnail setting. Maybe it will be helpful for you.

**Solution #1:**
Image vertical and horizontally center inside div

```
.thumb-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 60px;
        padding-bottom:45px; /* padding is using for the height of image */
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .thumb-img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 0px;
    }
    .thumb-img img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumb-container">
                                                            <div class="thumb-img"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97900&w=80&h=50"></div>
                                                        </div>
```

View on Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5az8u7bj/

**Solution #2:** Image vertical and horizontally center `width:100%` inside div fully cover image box no white space

```
.thumb-container {
           position: relative;
           padding-bottom:45px;
           margin: 0px;
           overflow: hidden;
           border: 1px solid black;
           width:60px;
        }
        .thumb-img {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 0px;
        }
        .thumb-img img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -100%;
            right: -100%;
            height:100%;
            margin: auto;
            width: auto;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumb-container">
                                                            <div class="thumb-img"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97900&w=500&h=200"></div>
                                                        </div>
```

View on JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2d6x3fn6/1/

Maybe these solution will be helpful for you